# Oracle query error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I'm quite new to Oracle and seem to having some problems with my query

Here's what i've got

```
SELECT (REPLACE(column1, 'test', '') + ': ' + column2) AS column3 FROM table
```

I get a `ORA-01722 invalid number` error with this.

I think it's something to do with the `+`'s but i'm not sure what the correct syntax is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use || to concat two strings...

```
SELECT (REPLACE(column1, 'test', '') || ': ' || column2) AS column3 FROM table
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to concatenate in Oracle is by using `||`

```
select 'a' || 'b' from dual;
```

Answer (score 4):

or by using the [CONCAT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions033.htm#SQLRF00619) function

(which nobody uses because the double pipe is easier to use, so just trying to be complete here)

Regards,
Rob.